# How to insert records to one table to another table using SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I Have two table name called Table1 & Table2.

**Table1:**

```
ID   NAME    AGE
-----------------
1    ABC     30
2    XYZ     40
3    XXX     50
4    aaa     60
```

**Table2:**

```
ID   NAME    AGE
-----------------
1    ABC     30
2    XYZ     40
3    XXX     50
```

I have to insert Table1 records to Table2. But I don't need to insert Existing item. I have to insert only unmatched data to Table2. How to do it.

E.g:
Table2 I am already have ID 1,2,3 but not 4. I have to insert only ID 4th rows.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
insert into Table2 
select * from Table1 t1 
where not exists (select 1 from Table2 t2 where t2.ID=t1.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `LEFT JOIN` too. Performance wise this is better than using `IN` operator.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ID, NAME, AGE)
SELECT T1.ID, T1.NAME, T1.AGE
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

---

Working execution with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), AGE INT)

INSERT INTO @Table1 (ID, NAME, AGE)
VALUES
(1, 'ABC', 30),
(2, 'XYZ', 40),
(3, 'XXX', 50),
(4, 'aaa', 60)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), AGE INT)

INSERT INTO @Table2 (ID, NAME, AGE)
VALUES
(1, 'ABC', 30),
(2, 'XYZ', 40),
(3, 'XXX', 50)

-- SELECT * FROM @Table2

INSERT INTO @Table2 (ID, NAME, AGE)
SELECT T1.ID, T1.NAME, T1.AGE
FROM @Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL

-- SELECT * FROM @Table2
```